# How do you use MongoDB $lookup to return a substring, then check things in another collection with that substring

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I am trying to use the MongoDB Aggregation pipeline to pull items from one collection, check a string (a url), extract a substring from that, then check in a second collection for a matching document to said substring off one of the second collection document fields.

collection1 document:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
    url: 'https://example.com/WNE8UH'
}
```

***edit: The productId is not always located at the end of the url string.  Sometimes it's right in the middle, which forces me to extract it before any comparison step.***

collection2 document:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
    productId: 'WNE8UH'
}
```

See the `url` in collection1 contains `WNE8UH` which is `productId` in collection2?

How do you use aggregation to return the substring of `url`, then use `$lookup` to locate the document in collection2 `productId` field?

Here is my current code:

```
db.collection1.aggregation([
    { $match: { url: RegExp( 'example.com', 'i' ) } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'collection2',
        
        let: {
            productId: { 
                $regexFind: { 
                    input: "$url", 
                    regex: '(?<=com\/)\w{6}'
             }
           }
        },
        pipeline: [
        {
            $match: { productId: '$$productId'
                }
        }
        ],
        as: 'matching_doc'
        
    }}
])
```

Result

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
    url: 'https://example.com/WNE8UH',
    matching_doc: []
}
```

Getting empty array.  I need to get the matching doc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: one thing that is wrong is this `{ $match: { productId: '$$productId'}}` . MongoDB variables are part of the aggregation framework, and they should be used with aggregate `$eq` and with `$expr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- lookup if `url` contains the `productId` in the end of the URL

*if this regex is not ok for your case you can use any other
*if you want to use an index to match the `url` you should create the index and also use regex with `^` like `^https://example.com/` (i mean before the lookup like in your query)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=625e06ac8b39bcf74dae273e)

```js
coll1.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
   {"from": "coll2",
    "let": {"url": "$url"},
    "pipeline": 
     [{"$match": 
         {"$expr": 
           {"$regexMatch": 
             {"input": "$$url",
              "regex": {"$concat": ["$productId", {"$literal": "$"}]}}}}}],
    "as": "matching_doc"}}])
```

---

Edit

In case that the `productId` is not in the end but it is always after the domain name here example.com you can use something like

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=625e1a448b39bcf74dae273f)

```js
coll1.aggregate(
[{"$lookup":
   {"from":"coll2",
    "pipeline":
     [{"$match":
         {"$expr":
           {"$regexMatch":
             {"input":"$$url",
              "regex":
               {"$concat":["^https://example.com/", "$productId", "*"]}}}}}],
    "as":"matching_doc",
    "let":{"url":"$url"}}}])
```

If it can be anywhere inside the URL you can use something like the bellow

```js
coll1.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
   {"from": "coll2",
    "pipeline": 
     [{"$match": 
         {"$expr": 
           {"$regexMatch": {"input": "$$url", "regex": "$productId"}}}}],
    "as": "matching_doc",
    "let": {"url": "$url"}}}])
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  Actually, the `productId` in collection 2 is not always found in the end of the url.  Do you have a way for that scenario?  That's why I was searching for a way to return a substring.  Here is a better example of that url:  `https://example.com/WNE8UH/product.html`.  How do you do it for this instance?